# Visual Studio does not recognize target framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have set my framework to 4.5.2 (see https://gyazo.com/004725305a2e3c4331a9a621adaab6a8)
    
 I have restarted visual studio, cleaned the project/solution, tried this process multiple times, yet visual studio still thinks I am on .NET 4.5

> ... which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".

Comment: something is building to fw4.5 while referencing assemblies or projects built to 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really cannot find what is the problem, then create a new project and move files to that project.

Alternatively, you can do a global search for `4.5` to see if you need to make some extra adjustment.

Also check references and config files.

Or maybe you somewhat mess up your computer.